# Android MapView parts of map missing

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

Any thoughts of what that might be?

[image]

The only manipulation I did to the overlay was to draw the pointer in the middle.

The code follows

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    Point myScreenCoords = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point, myScreenCoords);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.google_maps_marker);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x - (float)(bmp.getWidth() * 0.50),
                    myScreenCoords.y - bmp.getHeight(), paint);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: changing the zoom level does not have any effect.

Comment: it seems that it has something to do with the tile caching. at first the mapview is displayed correctly but if i switch to another activity and then back again the tiles above are missing